# How to combine sql query with a php array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, loops

i have been trying to solve this but i could not do it by myself

So i have this sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM stats WHERE date >= '2014-03-01' and date <= '2014-03-07'

+-----------------------------+
+ date        | visits        +
+-----------------------------+
+  2014-03-02 | 832           +
+  2014-03-03 | 746           +
+  2014-03-06 | 49            +                 
+-----------------------------+
```

I want to combine it with a php array so i get this output:

```
$array = array(
    "2014-03-01" => 0,
    "2014-03-02" => 832,
    "2014-03-03" => 746,
    "2014-03-04" => 0,
    "2014-03-05" => 0,
    "2014-03-06" => 49,
    "2014-03-07" => 0,
);
```

Does anyone know how to get this done?
Thank you very much for helping

Comment: Is `$array` already defined (with keys), or are you building it dynamically when you get your db values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First crate an array with :

```
$array1 = array(
    "2014-03-01" => 0,
    "2014-03-02" => 0,
    "2014-03-03" => 0,
    "2014-03-04" => 0,
    "2014-03-05" => 0,
    "2014-03-06" => 0,
    "2014-03-07" => 0,
);
```

Then get the array from db with:

```
$array2 = array(
    "2014-03-02" => 832,
    "2014-03-03" => 746,
    "2014-03-06" => 49,
);
```

Last get the result with:

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

(I know it's already answered)
The hard part (for me) was getting (@xdazz's) array1.
I found it at http://www.rarst.net/script/php-date-range/

```
$datearray1 = dateRange('2014/03/01', '2014/03/07');
$datearray1 = array_fill_keys($datearray1, 0);
$datearray2 = array('2014-03-02' => 832, '2014-03-03' => 746, '2014-03-06' => 49);
$datearray3 = array_replace($datearray1, $datearray2);
// http://www.rarst.net/script/php-date-range/
function dateRange($first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'Y-m-d' ) {
    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime( $first );
    $last = strtotime( $last );
    while( $current <= $last ) {
        $dates[] = date( $format, $current );
        $current = strtotime( $step, $current ); }
    return $dates;
  }
```